# How to include toolbar in my page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, http-error-500

in app/design/frontend/Main/Store/Magento_Theme/page_layout/ i created a shop.xml file that contains this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name='shop' class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Main_Store::product/shop.phtml">

            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

and now i want to add like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDRVf.png

i searched about it and i knew that its name is toolbar and it is in module-catalog , I don't know if it the same here in module-catalog/..../layout/catalog_category_view.xml

i tried many thing to display this toolbar on the page but i got 500 internel server error , what's the right way to add it without getting this error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try the following XML:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

If works, then change the template by your custom **Main_Store::product/shop.phtml** and compare with **Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml**